# How to sort, find and put one element on top?

Tags: javascript

How can I make sorting, with the condition - if an element named "Protein" exists in the array, find it, and always put it on top of the array.

My current sorting below.

```js
public getFilteredProbeGroups(): ipGroup[] {
    return this.probesSorting(this.filteredProbeGroups, this.selectedProbeGroupIds);
  }

  public probesSorting(probes: any[], selectedProbes: number[]): any[] {
    probes = probes.sort((a, b) => +selectedProbes.includes(b.id || b.probeGroupId) - +selectedProbes.includes(a.id || a.probeGroupId));
    const compareLoc = (a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
    return [...probes.filter(d => +selectedProbes.includes(d.id || d.probeGroupId)).sort(compareLoc),
      ...probes.filter(d => !+selectedProbes.includes(d.id || d.probeGroupId)).sort(compareLoc)];
  }
```

Comment: Provide example input and output please.

Comment: `if (a == 'Protein') return -1; if (b == 'Protein') return 1; ..rest of sort..`

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = ["Abcd", "Xyz", "Protein", "Mnop"]

let result = arr.sort((a,b) => a === "Protein" ? -1 : b === "Protein" ? 1 : a>b ? 1 : -1);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some generic implementation of bringing something to the start of an array:

```
function bringToTop<T>(ar: T[], shouldGoToTopFn: (item: T) => boolean): T[] {
    return [...ar].sort((a, b) => {
        const shouldA = shouldGoToTopFn(a);
        const shouldB = shouldGoToTopFn(b);
        return Number(shouldB) - Number(shouldA);
    });
}

console.log(bringToTop(
    ["Xyz", "Abcd", "Protein", "opop", "qwqwq"],
    (item) => item === 'Protein')
); // ["Protein", "Xyz", "Abcd", "opop", "qwqwq"]


// Negating condition makes 'Protein' go last instead
console.log(bringToTop(
    ["Xyz", "Abcd", "Protein", "opop", "qwqwq"],
    (item) => item !== 'Protein')
); // ["Xyz", "Abcd", "opop", "qwqwq", "Protein"]
```

This would also work for any kind of objects. And can bring multiple elements to top if `shouldGoToTopFn` returns true.